# Rename Azure Storage blobs to lower case by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I need to rename all blobs in a directory in azure storage to lower case as it is case sensitive.

I can do it by writing a c# program but a powershell script would be more convenient.

Does anyone has a script? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be aware that blobs cannot be renamed; you'd need to copy each one to a new blob, and then delete the old one when the copy operation is complete.

That said: For your PowerShell script, you could call `Get-AzureStorageBlob` to get the blobs in a container, and then loop through them with `For-EachObject`, executing a copy operation on (I believe `$_.Name` (I'll leave this to you to try). You can copy blobs via `Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob`, combined with `Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState` to know when the copy is complete.

Comment: Thx. I know blob can be copied only. Seems like also need to check the status in a callback manner. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Since you're renaming blobs i.e. copying blobs in same container, copy function works synchronously. Thus you don't really need to check the status. Status check is required when the blobs are copied asynchronously across storage accounts.